# Undelete map on Reportserver for Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I deleted the map with all reports on the SQL Server Report Server, assuming I could delete the reportrecords in CRM manually and configure a map to which the reports are pointing manually. However this does not seem to be the case. I cannot delete the reportrecords in CRM manually, it requires that the reports on the SSRS exist.

How can I recreate the map on the SSRS that CRM looks for. I remember the name was something like:

```
<orginization name>_MSCRM {<some guid>}
```

Which guid is it using and how can I find the exact syntax of the map on the SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% on this, but you could try a repair installation of the CRM application, hopefully that should restore the ReportServer to a working state.